# Apply Table of Search Criteria to a Value to Determine a Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

We are running a database on SQL Server 2016.  In this database we have a stored procedure that periodically processes received message records and creates entries in a transaction table.  We have recently added an extra field that contains a location code and I need to map this to an internal ID value.  The location codes will look something like:

```
A.12.10.3
QUAY
HD.STACK
CDC.MT
MT.STACK
```

I want to create a table of rules to evaluate the codes received and map them to IDs.  A lot of the location codes are similar format so I would like something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE LOCATION_MAP (
  CRITERIA NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  LOCATIONID INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_LOCATION_MAP PRIMARY KEY (CRITERIA, LOCATIONID)
);
```

I would then have values in the table like:

```
CRITERIA   LOCATIONID
A.%        1
CDC.%      2
QUAY       3
HD.%       4
```

(I'm using the % symbol in the same way SQL Server uses it for LIKE conditions).

What would be the best way to apply the search criteria to the field value?

Comment: How many values do you expect in the table over time? Your clever shortcut may cut down on number of records in the table but if your semantics ever change then you will not be able to get  the complete list back. If the number of entries are manageable then just stuff all of them in a table and be done with it.

Comment: I'm trying to keep the table limited by keeping the format of the location codes standard (so everything at one location would be CDC. for example).

Comment: I actually already figured this out...  SELECT * FROM LOCATION_MAP WHERE (@LOCATIONCODE LIKE CRITERIA) works.  Should have thought of this earlier!